# How do I give write only access to a Google TeamDrive subfolder

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-drive-sharing

I setup a TeamDrive with sub-folders (handins and handouts). I want people to be able to write to the handins folder but not view, and view and edit in the handouts folder.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying any kind of permissions to folders inside Team Drives isn't possible at this time.